# How Italian "dito" was derived from Latin DĬGĬTU(M)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, sound-change, italian, catalan

I'm trying to figure out which phenomena may be involved in the development of Italian "dito" from Latin DĬGĬTU(M).

I think one of them may be a loss of intervocalic -G-, as explained in this [article](https://www.academia.edu/33434684/_Revisiting_the_History_of_Tuscan_Consonants_The_Type_st%C3%B9pito_stupid_STUP%C4%ACDU_M_Zeitschrift_f%C3%BCr_romanische_Philologie_133_2017_2_549_584) for other words. This is also explained in the book *Lineamenti di grammatica storica dell'italiano* by Giuseppe Patota (Bologna, il Mulino, 2002):

> In posizione interna la velare sonora, dopo essersi palatalizzata, ha subito un'ulteriore trasformazione, e in alcuni casi si è intensificata (come in LĔGIT > *legge*), in altri si è dileguata perché assorbita da una I successiva, detta **omorganica** perché pronunciata con gli stessi organi articolatori della consonante precedente (in entrambi i casi si tratta di foni palatali). Per esempio, dalla base latina SAGĬTTA(M), alla palatalizzazione della velare ([sa'ʤitta]) è seguito il suo dileguo, che ha prodotto SAĬTTA e poi *saetta*, con regolare trasformazione della Ĭ tonica in *e* chiusa [e].

My translation:

> In internal position the voiced velar, after being palatalized, has undergone further transformation, and in some cases has been intensified (as in LĔGIT > *legge*), in other ones it was lost because it has been absorbed by a subsequent I, said **homorganic** because it's pronounced with the same articulatory organs as the previous consonant (in both cases they are palatal phones). For instance, from the Latin base SAGĬTTA(M), to the palatalization of the velar ([sa'ʤitta]) followed its lost, which has produced SAĬTTA and then *saetta*, with regular transformation of the tonic Ĭ into closed *e*, that is, [e].

But then, these two Ĭ in contact in *DĬĬTU, could they have behaved like a sort of long vowel, in such a way that the development Ī > [i] was involved? Has this any sense?

My problem is that I don't know if [ii] > [i:] is an usual development in Vulgar Latin or in early Romance languages (in particular, in early Florentine), although it seems reasonable to me.

I imagine that something similar to Italian happened in Catalan (one of my native languages), in which DĬGĬTU(M) > *dit*.

---

I've seen that, according to Daniel Recasens i Vives, what it happened in this case both in Tuscan Italian and in Catalan, is the evolution GI > [j] followed by the loss of this [j].

In RECASENS, D., "Velar and dental stop softening in Romance", published in *Diachronica*, 28:2, (2011), 186-224, there is a section in which the author is analyzing the phonetic outcomes for intervocalic GI/E, GY, DY and I in different Romance languages showing the differences on the place of articulation.
In this section, there is a note which states:

> Minor phonetic solutions deviating from the general pattern have not been included in the
> tables, e.g., [j] or zero for GI/E and an alveolar affricate for DY in Tuscan Italian words ([ˈdito]
> DIGITU “finger”, [sarˈtana] SARTAGINE “pan”, [ˈmeddzo] MEDIU “half (masc. sing.)”).

The book *Fonètica històrica del català* by the same author (Barcelona, Institut d'Estudis Catalans, 2017) explains something similar for Catalan in a section in which the author is analyzing the different outcomes of the sequences J, B[j]-V[j], D[j], GE and GI:

> En alguns vocables del català general la solució fonètica dels grups consonàntics que ens ocupen ha estat [j] o l'elisió de la consonant. 
>
> Alguns mots experimentaren elisió d'una realització afeblida [j] de [ɟ] provinent de G*e*,*i*, ja en llatí vulgar, per superposició gestual i/o confusió perceptiva entre aquest gradual i una vocal anterior immediatament precedent o següent. Exemples: *mestre* MAGISTRU, *vint* VIGINTI, *ficar* *FICCARE < *FIGICARE,
> *dit* *DITU < DIGITU, *fred* FRIGIDU, *mai*, *més* MAIS < MAGIS; *cuidar* COGITARE (cat. ant. *cug*, *cuyg* amb africada; DECat, vol. 2, p. 1091).

My translation:

> In some general Catalan words the phonetic solution of the consonantic sequences that concern us has been [j] or the loss of the consonant. 
>
> Some words experienced the loss of a weak realization [j] of [ɟ] coming from GE or GI already in Vulgar Latin, through gestural blending and/or perceptive confusion of this gradual release and an immediately preceding or following front vowel. Examples: *mestre* MAGISTRU, *vint* VIGINTI, *ficar* *FICCARE < *FIGICARE,
> *dit* *DITU < DIGITU, *fred* FRIGIDU, *mai*, *més* MAIS < MAGIS; *cuidar* COGITARE (old Catalan *cug*, *cuyg* with affricate;
> *Diccionari etimològic i complementari de la llengua catalana*, vol. 2, p. 1091).

So, according to Recasens, for both Italian *dito* and Catalan *dit*

> DĬGĬTU(M) > *DĬTU.

However, this doesn't explain how one gets [i] from Ĭ.

Comment: Since Italian doesn't have long vowel phonemes, what's not clear about  Ī > [i] development?

Comment: @YellowSky: The point is that there are two Ĭ in the Latin word, not an Ī.

Comment: @Charo That’s a pretty trivial change, though. I’d say it’d be harder to find a language where /i.i/ **doesn’t** eventually become /i:/ over time than one where it does. You do sometimes see dissimilations like /i.i/ > /ei/, especially if the sounds belong to separate morphemes (and in fact I think something like that must have happened in French/Spanish/Portuguese, which all have reflexes of earlier /e:/), but I don’t think that applies to Italian.

Comment: I'm sorry if the answer of my question is so simple. I'm newbie in historical Romance linguistics. Can anyone please write an answer?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: After reading the works of Recasens, this doesn't seem so trivial to me.

Comment: As I read the two sources you’ve added, post-vocalic /gi/ was weakened to /ji/ in some Romance languages/dialects. In Tuscan, that /ji/ subsequently disappeared completely (compare _sartana_ with Sicilian _sartayina_, according to Wiktionary, where the intermediate stage is still visible). In Catalan, the /j/ appears to have disappeared throughout, but the /i/ remained. In both cases, if this /ji/ came after an /i/ (so /igi/ > /iji/), the whole thing in one way or another ended up as just /i/ – likely through /iji/ > /ii/ > /i:/ > /i/ in both languages.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I don't understand why do you say this. As I said, in the paper by Recasens, there is a section in which the author is analyzing the phonetic outcomes for intervocalic GI/E, GY, DY and I in different Romance languages and says that there are some minor phonetic solutions that hadn't been shown in the table with such outcomes, giving the example of DĬGĬTU > *dito* in which GI > [j] > zero. (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) In the book by Recasens, the author is analyzing the different outcomes of the sequences J, B[j]-V[j], D[j], GE and GI (sorry, I've just added this) in Catalan. After explaining the general evolution in different cases, it's stated that sometimes GI/GE > [j] and sometimes [j] > zero. In addition, I'm not sure that the Sicilian outcome is the same as the Tuscan one (in a previous stage): the paper by Recasens shows lots of different solutions.

Comment: Note also that is not the most usual evolution neither in Italian nor in Catalan.